# Vertical text writing with animation? Bug in the css code

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to write vertically the text in which the animation is included. After numerous attempts, I was unable to determine where I was wrong, or what to change in this code. Attached I am sending an image showing the output of the code.
If anyone knows the solution, let them leave a comment, thanks.

---

Additional explanation:

I want to write the text vertically. I have shown this in the picture. The picture shows that one part is written vertically, while the text in which I built the animation via css code, unfortunately remains written horizontally.

Now I'm confused, what do I need to change in the CSS code in order to get that text, which has animation, written via csss code, to be written vertically as well.

[image: preview]

---

```css
.test2 {
      writing-mode: vertical-rl; 
    }
    
    body {background:transparent;}
    .smrtn1kloading {
      font-family: "Arial Black", "Arial Bold", Gadget, sans-serif;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      
      width:150px;
      text-align:center;
      line-height:50px;
      
      position:absolute;
      left:0;right:0;top:50%;
      margin:auto;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    .smrtn1kloading span {
      position:relative;
      z-index:999;
      color:#fff;
    }
    .smrtn1kloading:before {
      content:'';
      background:#1b8aca;
      width:360px;
      height:36px;
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
      margin:auto;
      
      animation:2s smrtn1kloadingBefore infinite ease-in-out;
    }
    
    @keyframes smrtn1kloadingBefore {
      0%   {transform:translateX(-14px);}
      50%  {transform:translateX(14px);}
      100% {transform:translateX(-14px);}
    }
    
    
    .smrtn1kloading:after {
      content:'';
      background:#242424;
      width:14px;
      height:60px;
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
      margin:auto;
      opacity:.5;
      
      animation:2s smrtn1kloadingAfter infinite ease-in-out;
    }
    
    @keyframes smrtn1kloadingAfter {
      0%   {transform:translateX(-50px);}
      50%  {transform:translateX(50px);}
      100% {transform:translateX(-50px);}
    }
    
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
    <table>
        <tbody><tr><td><p class="test2">Preusmeri na <div class="smrtn1kloading">
            <a href="https://ljubinko-stojanovic-smrtnik-privatna-baza-podataka.webnode.com/krajiske-lingvisticke-doskocice">
                <span>Krajiške</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>lingvističke</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>doskočice.</span></a></div></p></td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
```

---

Comment: Could you describe your goal better? Maybe add an image?

Comment: I need to write the text vertically. I created a class that prints text in that direction. However, when I add an animation, the text is positioned approximately in the middle of the web page.